# inner product space , dual space, proof about isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space (not necessary being finite dimensional) and let $U,W$ be 
subspaces of $V$ such that $V = U\oplus W$.

Prove that $V^\ast/(W^0)$ is isomorphic to $W^\ast$.

---

Notation and Definitions:

- $W^0$ is the annihilator of $W$
- $W^0=\{f \in V^\ast\mid \text{f(v)=0, for all v in W}\}$
- $V^\ast$ is the dual space of $V$

---

Before doing this proof, I have a question: when we construct a mapping from
$V^\ast$ to $W^\ast$, do we need $W^0$ to be the kernel of that mapping?

Comment: If you plan on using the First Isomorphism theorem in order to establish the fact that $V^\ast/W^0\cong W^\ast$, then yes, you will need the linear transformation $T:V^\ast \rightarrow W^\ast$ to have kernel exactly $W^0$.

Comment: But how do we construct the mapping from V* to W*?

Comment: @KevinLee : Just restrict a linear functional on $V$ to $W$ - this will give you the mapping $V^{\ast} \to W^{\ast}$

Comment: I atempt to prove (i)Im(ϕ)=W* (ii)ker(ϕ)=W^0

Comment: for (i), I can prove Im(ϕ) contained in W*, but the converse direction I have no ideas, i.e., W* contained in ker(ϕ).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following linear mapping,
$$\phi:V^*/W^o \rightarrow W^*$$
$$[f]\longmapsto f|_W$$
Lets see if it's well defined, consider $f,g\in V^*$ such that $[f]=[g]$, this means $f-g\in W^o$. Now given any $w\in W$ we have that:
\begin{align*}
(f-g)(w)&=0\\
\Rightarrow f(w)&=g(w)\\
\Rightarrow f|_W&=g|_W\\
\end{align*}

Next we are going to prove that $\phi$ is inyective, if $f$ is such that $\phi(f)=0\in W^*$ we have that 
$$\forall w\in W:\quad f|_W(w)=0$$
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow f&\in W^o\\
\Rightarrow [f]&=0
\end{align*}

Finally lets see if $\phi$ is onto. Take any $g\in W^*$, we define $f\in V^*$ such that $f(v=u+w)=g(w)$ where $u+w$ is the unique decomposition of $v$ given by $V=U\oplus W$. $f$ is clearly linear and $f|W=g$.

Comment: Hello Julio C'aceres, thanks for your proof. But in your beginning of the proof, you define φ:V*/W^0-->W*, how do we verify that ker(φ)=W^0 ?

Comment: Here I find the same question of other's ask. He applies the first homomorphism theorm in the final step.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295064/show-that-w-is-naturally-isomorphic-to-v-w0

Comment: Well the $\ker(\phi)$ is $[0]\in V^*/W^o$ since the map is inyective, but $[0]=W^o$.

Comment: I didn't used the first isomorphism theorem, I constructed the map directly :P

Comment: Thank you for help~! Mucho gracias~!

Comment: No problem, and if you think this is an acceptable answer please mark it down as such :P